# Why is there no stand-alone Tor binaries for OS X and Linux on dist?

Tags: linux, mac

I have used the stand-alone Windows ZIP file (with just tor.exe) in it with great success:
https://dist.torproject.org/torbrowser/8.5.4/tor-win32-0.4.0.5.zip

However there doesn't seem to be any counterpart for Linux and OS X.

There is the entire browser bundle, e.g.
https://dist.torproject.org/torbrowser/8.5.4/tor-browser-linux64-8.5.4_en-US.tar.xz

But this is much larger and contains an entire web browser in addition to the Tor binary. Why is this?

I understand many people on Linux get Tor via their distro package manager but it's strange to me that no trimmed down offering like the Windows ZIP is available.

Comment: Maybe here: https://archive.torproject.org/tor-package-archive/torbrowser/?

Answer (score 1):

In almost every Linux and BSD distribution you can install the Tor service using the package management. Tor even provides this themselves for [Debian and Ubuntu](https://2019.www.torproject.org/docs/debian.html.en). Most good distros even keep their Tor packages up to date with the latest updates.

I can't say anything about Macs because I don't use them.

Comment: I figured that was the answer but it seems a little incongruous with the Tor browser bundles that are available per-platform. Wouldn't those come through the OS package manager as well ideally? Anyhow, thanks for the input.